# Incorrect Spacing Between Sentences Ellipsis

Tags: spacing, csquotes, quotation, ellipsis

I am testing using increased spacing between sentences. I am finding that LaTeX does not add spacing at the end of a sentence that ends in an ellipsis or an ellipsis followed by a closing quote. I would like to tell LaTeX that the sentence ends at the ellipsis or the ellipsis followed by a closing quote. I can't seem to find a way to manually insert the increased spacing that should appear at the end of a sentence or tell LaTeX that the sentence ends at a particular point. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I figured out how to manually insert the spacing at the end of the sentence "\hspace{\fontdimen7\font} " This is useful in niche situations where the TeX algorithm falls short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\raggedright
%frenchspacing is OFF
\begin{document}
\textbf{Correct spacing between sentences:}\par
He reached the quarter-finals of the 1981 UK Championship by eliminating Geoff Foulds, Fred Davis and Doug Mountjoy from the competition before being defeated 5–9 by Terry Griffiths. Later that season, Knowles gained attention when he won 10–1 against defending champion Steve Davis in the first round of the 1982 World Snooker Championship, after staying out late at a nightclub following the first day's play when he had built an 8–1 lead. He defeated Miles 13–7 in the second round, before losing 11–13 to Eddie Charlton in the quarter-finals.\par
\textbf{Incorrect spacing after \ldots{}\textquotedblright{} and before \enquote{Ten century}}\par
\enquote{\ldots{}Davis was the bookmaker's favourite to win the tournament, but he lost 1–10 to Tony Knowles in the\ldots{}} Ten century breaks were made during the tournament, the highest of which was a 143 scored by Willie Thorne.\par
\textbf{Correct spacing between sentences:}\par
I love latex. I am here to learn latex! Hello world.\par%using latex in all lowercase just for example
\textbf{Incorrect spacing between sentences:}\par
I love latex\ldots{} I am here to learn latex\ldots{} Hello world.\par
\textbf{Incorrect spacing between sentences:}\par
\enquote{I love latex\ldots{}} \enquote{I am here to learn latex\ldots{}} Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: mwe]

The inter-sentence extra space in your MWE already exists and it is always there. I guess that you see differences due to the space inherent to the punctuation marks.

If you want to see some more extra space after the sentences, you must check that `\frenchspacing` is NOT activated (i.e., "french spacing" mean  "no extra spacing, thaks") and take care of inter-sentence glue, that is `\xspaceskip`. When this length is not set, or set to 0pt, then the glue is obtained from `\fontdimen7\font`. THe default of this parameter is ratter small so the  `\nonfrenchspacing` could be hardly noticeable.

Setting a large `\fontdimen7\font` or `\xspaceskip` (said, 20 pt) you will see  clearly that LaTeX add the same(*) extra space also after the sentences ended with quotes or ellipsis.

(*) As the space could be a glue (i.e., a stretchable and shrinkable space like `20pt  plus 1pt minus 2pt`)  some differences is not a LaTeX mistake, but a trick to obtain better line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\raggedright
\begin{document}

\bigskip\frenchspacing \verb-\frenchspacing-\bigskip 


I love latex. I am here to learn latex! Hello world.\par%using latex in all lowercase just for example
I love latex\ldots{} I am here to learn latex\ldots{} Hello world.\par
\enquote{I love latex\ldots{}} \enquote{I am here to learn latex\ldots{}} Hello world.


\bigskip\nonfrenchspacing\verb-\nonfrenchspacing-\bigskip 


\verb-\fontdimen7\font=-\the\fontdimen7\font\ (default)\bigskip

I love latex. I am here to learn latex! Hello world.\par%using latex in all lowercase just for example
I love latex\ldots{} I am here to learn latex\ldots{} Hello world.\par
\enquote{I love latex\ldots{}} \enquote{I am here to learn latex\ldots{}} Hello world.

\bigskip\fontdimen7\font=40pt \verb-\fontdimen7\font=40pt-\bigskip

I love latex. I am here to learn latex! Hello world.\par%using latex in all lowercase just for example
I love latex\ldots{} I am here to learn latex\ldots{} Hello world.\par
\enquote{I love latex\ldots{}} \enquote{I am here to learn latex\ldots{}} Hello world.


\bigskip
\setlength{\xspaceskip}{10pt} \verb-\setlength{\xspaceskip}{20pt}-%
\bigskip

I love latex. I am here to learn latex! Hello world.\par%using latex in all lowercase just for example
I love latex\ldots{} I am here to learn latex\ldots{} Hello world.\par
\enquote{I love latex\ldots{}} \enquote{I am here to learn latex\ldots{}} Hello world.


\end{document}
```